# DropDownList.SelectedIndex sets to 1

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

["DropDownList.SelectedIndex = -1" problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/81379/11582004)

I used the above solution to set my DropDownlist and it is working as expected. But I have noticed **an intermittent bug**, where after the Insert Item at index 0 using below code
`myDropDownList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please select", ""));`
The **myDropDownList.SelectedIndex is set to 1**

Comment: You get this problem if the data set ALSO has a blank row. So you are adding a row, and a blank one exists. So, it will often select 0 or 1 for the index. If you prevent the database/dataset from having a blank row in the data, then you should always get 0. If you have a blank row AND you add the blank row? Then you get 1 or often will.

Answer (score 0):

Did u put it on the Page_Load ? or maybe u have some more info? Small example of code here its VB.NET but u should get the idea.

```
   Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not Me.IsPostBack Then

        MyDropDownList.SelectedIndex = -1
        
    End If



End Sub
```

***EDIT
This is how i do it in my projects.(i fill the dropdown from a database here.)

```
 Private Sub Fill_DropDown()
    dsItems= SqlHelper.ReadOnlyDataset("SELECT Item FROM Items ORDER BY ID")
    
    ws_Items.Items.Add("Choose Item...")

    For Each row As DataRow In dsItems.Tables(0).Rows
        ws_Items.Items.Add(row("Items"))
    Next

    ws_Items.SelectedIndex = 0
End Sub
```

And then on the load i do this

```
   Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Me.IsPostBack Then

      Call Fill_DropDown()

    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah, it is in PageLoad inside if condition `if (!IsPostBack){}`

Comment: Well you can use databind - don't really need a loop. But as noted, if the data set has a blank row, and you add a blank row, then your index is pushed down one, and you get a value of 1 - so make sure the dataset does not have that blank row (or if it does/will, then don't add a 2nd blank row as you are).